# Python import type detection

Tags: python, module, import

Can a python module detect if has been imported with `import module` or `from module import *`? Something like

```
 if __something__=='something':
      print 'Directly imported with "import ' + __name__ + '"'
 else:
      print 'Imported with "from ' + __name__ + ' import *"'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Needing to depend on this sounds very, very broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to detect this from within the module's code.  Upon the first import, the module body is executed and a new module object is inserted in `sys.modules`.  Only after this, the requested names are inserted into the namespace of the importing module.

Upon later imports, the module body isn't even executed.  So if a module is first  imported as

```
import module
```

and a second time as

```
from module import name
```

it has no chance to do anything at all during the second import.  In particular, it cannot check how it is imported.

Answer (score 0):

While Svens answer is probably the correct one, and this might seem a bit obvious, It is what I was really looking for when I stumbled upon this question.

This module will at least know that you passed an input argument to it. While allows unit testing of just this specific script without the unit test being performed in the module that imported it.

```
import sys

def myfunction(blah):
    return "something like: " + blah

noargs=len(sys.argv)
if noargs>1:
    for i in range(noargs-1):
        print myfunction(sys.argv[i+1])
```

However, It doesn't really help you, Emilio, if you have no input arguments. : )