# How to check why a python module is being imported?

Tags: python, import

I have a big library of python modules. Sometimes, when importing a module, I see that unexpected modules are being imported. For this, I have been using `python -v`, to see which modules are being imported. From the manpage:

```
-v     Print  a  message  each  time a module is initialized, showing the place
       (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded.  When given twice,
       print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a
       module.  Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.
```

Well, this is not true. For example:

```
import portalmq # directory /home/blahblah/python_modules/portalmq
# /home/blahblah/python_modules/portalmq/__init__.pyc matches /home/blahblah/python_modules/portalmq/__init__.py
import portalmq # precompiled from /home/blahblah/python_modules/portalmq/__init__.pyc
```

As you can see, the `-v`flag just gives me information about which modules are imported, but not about which import statement, in which file/line is triggering the import. Using `-vv` does not change anything (a list of tried modules is shown, but nothing about why the import is tried in the first place)

But I need to know exactly that: which import statement, in which file/line is triggering those imports. How can I get this information?

Comment: slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983522/

Answer (score 5):

Import hooks! Just add this code to your main script entry point to track every import after the `sys.meta_path.append` is executed.

```
import traceback

class TracingFinder:
    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        print 'loading module', fullname
        traceback.print_stack()

import sys
sys.meta_path.append(TracingFinder())
```

Test:

```
def foo():
    import test
    import this

foo()
```

Output:

```
loading module test
  File "moo.py", line 15, in <module>
    foo()
  File "moo.py", line 12, in foo
    import test
  File "moo.py", line 6, in find_module
    traceback.print_stack()
loading module this
  File "moo.py", line 15, in <module>
    foo()
  File "moo.py", line 13, in foo
    import this
  File "moo.py", line 6, in find_module
    traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: What!? Don't tell me that the python binary is not able to provide this information out-of-the-box!!!

Comment: What you posted is working, thanks. I am still surprised that python can not give me this information without extra hacking, though.

Comment: @gonvaled: and are there interpreters that do give you this information? Here it is just a few lines of code to add this instrumentation, and it is quite flexible (you can do a lot of things with import hooks).

Comment: how do you detect from module `foo` whether `foo` is executed due to being imported (instead of due to command line)? Problem is that I guess, `import foo` already has taken place by the point `foo` gets a chance to install the import hook. At least this is the behavior I get.

Comment: @naxa: that's what the standard `if __name__ == '__main__'` test does.

Comment: @nneonneo thanks! I should've explained, I was unhappy with that because interactive interpreter sessions tend not to set the `__name__` to `'__main__'`, a very corner case I sometimes attempt to address.

Comment: Interactive interpreter sessions? How are you running your code?